# Strange limitation in the implementation of internal interface

Tags: c#, theory

I have code

```
internal interface IFoo
{
  void foo();
}

public class A : IFoo
{
  // error CS0737: 'A' does not implement interface member 'IFoo.foo()'. 
  //'A.foo()' cannot implement an interface member because it is not public.
  internal void foo()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("A");
  }
}
```

Why such strange limitation? I have internal interface and why I can't create internal method in interface realization?

Comment: you cannot have a public class, which is exposed outside, implementing an internal interface which would not be exposed. Does not make sense.

Comment: Have you try to implement the interface explicitly : void IFoo.foo() { /* stuff */ }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because interfaces can't specify anything about the visibility of members, only the members themselves. All members that implement an interface must be `public`. The same happens when you implement a `private` interface.

One solution might be explicitly implementing the interface:

```
internal interface IFoo
{
  void foo();
}

public class A : IFoo
{
  void IFoo.foo()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("A");
  }
}
```

In the above code, you must have an instance of `A` cast to `IFoo` to be able to call `foo()`, but you can only do such a cast if you are `internal` compared to the class and hence have access to `IFoo`.

Comment: Remove the "public" part from the implementation - it should just be `void IFoo.foo()`

Comment: I known about explicit interface realization. But I don't understand this limitations reason in C#.

Comment: @JonSkeet could probably explain much better than I can, he has a knack for noticing edge cases. I'm not actually sure *why* myself, I just know how it is.

Comment: Basically members of interfaces are *always* public. This is annoying :( In fact, [I've blogged about it before now](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/10/03/the-curious-case-of-the-publicity-seeking-interface-and-the-shy-abstract-class.aspx)